# Text box in menu win32 C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a windows app on which when I do a right click a lot of options are shown in the pop up context menu.   How can one place an edit text box,  in the context menu so that I can type something (and on the change of text box disable few  menu items ) . I tried something like this . This doesn't work.

```
  HWND hWndEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"), TEXT("test"),
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 20, 140,
        20, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

AppendMenu(MyLocalRightClick, MF_STRING, (UINT)hWndEdit,NULL);
```

Comment: This is not something that's supported by [menus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/menus). Menus cannot have child controls.

Comment: You can't add child controls to the menu bar, it only supports the [provided styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-appendmenua#parameters). Also, you can't set `WS_CHILD` without setting the parent window.